# automatically enabling macros in excel c#

Tags: c#, excel, vba, visual-studio

I am accessing data from an embedded excel sheet through c#, but in order for the script to read the excel sheet I must manually press "enable macros" every time. How can I write a script such that it automatically enables macros every time? I am opening various excels so cannot change the settings on the excel sheet itself.

I saw something regarding the use of VBA but am unsure what to do? Would using this reference (using VBA = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop) be helpful?

The code below simply opens the excel, but I still have to click enable macros.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

wordApp = new Word.Application();
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@"Y:DocumentName");
Word.InlineShapes ils = wordDoc.InlineShapes;
ils[1].OLEFormat.Activate();
xlWorkBook = ils[1].OLEFormat.Object;
```

Comment: Have lower-security macro security settings, or make your file a trusted document. There is no programmatic way to enable macros, it's a security thing. Every macro-virus would do that otherwise.

Comment: Not sure if it meant that way but this sounds malicious.

Comment: If someone's able to answer this, I would love to know. (As would the MS folks too, I'm sure). @MathieuGuindon has a great point.

Comment: There are scripts out there that will allow you to access the VBA Object directly and then turn off those security settings, but it opens up a slew of security issues and is NOT recommended.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried setting the DisplayAlerts property to false?

```
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

Comment: Just turning off alerts wouldn't override the security settings in Excel, so I doubt this would work.  Please see Mathieu's post above.

Comment: It works for me but I have the Trust Center configured for 'Disable all macros with notification' enabled.